# Slick2D Particle System does not spawn particles

Tags: java, slick2d

I have this in one of my classes (in the class that i want the particle to exist). This is some of the code from the init method

```
public void init(GameContainer c, StateBasedGame sbg) throws SlickException {
    drop = new Image("Fishing/drop.png");
    system = new ParticleSystem(drop,1500);
    try{
        File xmlFile = new File("particles/healing.xml");
        ConfigurableEmitter emitter = ParticleIO.loadEmitter(xmlFile);
        emitter.setPosition(400, 400);
        system.addEmitter(emitter);
    } catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Exception: "+e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(0);
    }
```

And this is whats in the healing.xml file..

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<emitter imageName="" name="Healing Particle">
  <spawnInterval enabled="true" max="150.0" min="100.0"/>
  <spawnCount enabled="true" max="3.0" min="1.0"/>
  <initialLife enabled="true" max="1000.0" min="500.0"/>
  <initialSize enabled="true" max="15.0" min="5.0"/>
  <xOffset enabled="true" max="4.0" min="-4.0"/>
  <yOffset enabled="true" max="4.0" min="-4.0"/>
  <initialDistance enabled="false" max="0.0" min="0.0"/>
  <speed enabled="true" max="50.0" min="12.0"/>
  <length enabled="false" max="1000.0" min="500.0"/>
  <spread value="40.0"/>
  <angularOffset value="0.0"/>
  <growthFactor value="20.0"/>
  <gravityFactor value="0.0"/>
  <startAlpha value="255.0"/>
  <endAlpha value="0.0"/>
  <color>
    <step b="0.0" g="0.0" offset="0.0" r="1.0"/>
    <step b="0.0" g="0.0" offset="0.336" r="1.0"/>
    <step b="0.0" g="0.0" offset="1.0" r="1.0"/>
  </color>
</emitter>
```

The particles dont show up. I also used system.render(); in the render method and system.update(delta); on the update method. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use the fire Emitter which is part of the slick2d library.

http://slick.ninjacave.com/javadoc/org/newdawn/slick/particles/effects/FireEmitter.html

Does this work for you? In case it does either your update / render method are not working correctly or your .XML is not valid. (Both look fine for me tho). Your init looks fine as well. But try a simple .XML where you are sure that it works.

I often experienced no particles showing up by messing around with my .XML

Furthermore check out this tutorial in case you didn't already:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Re5XJiWy4eQ

It provides a demo which you could test as well.

In case all Demos / tests do not work I assume that your Computer configuration is responsible for not showing These particles.